# Linq to Entities 3.5 where most recent date

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table and for the sake of the example lets say it has three columns: Name, DateAdded, Note. In this table there will be multiple records with the same name. I need a linq where clause that will get me a result set with the most recent record for each name.

So if I had the following information:

```
Name, DateAdded, Note
Alpha, 1/1/2010, note one
Alpha, 1/2/2010, note two
Alpha, 1/3/2010, note three
Beta, 1/4/2010, note four
Beta, 1/5/2010, note five
```

I would expect to get the following results:

```
Name, DateAdded, Note
Alpha, 1/3/2010, note three
Beta, 1/5/2010, note five
```

In real use this is going to be a search option so I need it to be a .Where clause I can append to an IQueryable collection if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
from row in rows
group row by row.Name into grouping
from g in grouping
where g.DateAdded == grouping.Max(x => x.DateAdded)
select g;
```

If there's more than one row with the maximum `DateAdded` in some group, this returns all such rows.

You don't need just one `Where` clause. If `rows` is a `IQueryable`, then the result of this query is too, so you can use it as a part of a chain. But I have no idea how well does this query translate to SQL.

Comment: You may try something like `where g == grouping.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded).First()` instead to be sure to get a single row for each group.

Comment: I'm not sure why your code didn't work for me but I was able to do it like this:

    results = results.Where(i => i.DateAdded == context.rows.Where(o => o.row.name == i.row.name).OrderByDescending(o => o.DateAdded).FirstOrDefault().DateAdded);

Thanks for the help.